# multiple modules instantiation declaration and function verilog

Tags: verilog

I have instantiated 4 modules. The third module called does not get input, in its if block input turns zero, but it runs fine when the module is executed separately and not called from this main module. Can anyone tell me why isn't it getting input?
Kindly go through the third module

```
module one(u,v,p,x,x2,rx,clk,rem);
input [15:0]u,v,p;
input clk;
output wire [15:0]rx,rem;
output wire [31:0]x,x2;
rcalci inst(.p(p),.clk1(clk),.r(rx));
vedic_16x16 inst2(.a(u),.b(rx),.c(x));
division1 inst3(.n(x),.d(p),.clk2(clk),.r(rem));
vedic_16x16 inst4(.a(v),.b(rx),.c(x2));
endmodule

module division1(n,d,clk2,r);
input [31:0]n;
input [15:0]d;
output [15:0]r;
reg [15:0]r,q;
reg [15:0]n1,n2;
input clk2;
integer i=0;
reg [1:0]flag;
initial
    flag=0;
always @(posedge clk2)
begin
    if(flag==0)
    begin
        n1[15:0]=n[31:16];
        n2[15:0]=n[15:0];
        flag=1;
    end

    if(flag==1)
    begin
        r=n2[15:0];    
        if(i<16)
        begin
            n1[15:0]={n1[14:0],n2[15]};
            n2=n2<<1;

            if(n1>=d)
            begin
                n1=n1-d;
                n2[0]=1;
                //q=n2;
            end

        end
        i=i+1;
        if(i>=16)
            flag=2;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`division1` input `n` is only sampled on the first clock, and once one division is complete no other operations are performed. This input is derived from `rx` which appears to be updated by the same clock. It is extremely unlikely that `n` will have the expected value by the time it is sampled by `division1`.

I don't know the intend of your code. One option is to set `flag` back to 0 instead of 2 and reset `i` so division will happen again. Another option is to start the division on a latter clock edge. I'm guessing you want the first option.

Also, sequential logic should be assigned with non-blocking assignments (`<=`) not blocking (`=`).

Comment: So i need to use "<=" in the dividion module instead of "=" ?

Comment: How can is I start division from latter edge ?

Comment: You can always an another input signal to indicate when to start. There are plenty of online resources explain where and why to use blocking and non-blocking assignment. Here is one such paper: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf